# .Net and SQL - Transactions with long running processes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, transactions

I have a method in .Net (v4.6 using Dapper), named BulkUpdate, that will modify several tables and can include around 10,000 rows or more. This operation can take a few seconds to a couple of minutes depending on the number of data being inserted. Since I will be updating multiple related tables I have to enclose all operations in a `TransactionScope`.

My question is what is the best way to avoid other read requests (outside the Transaction) from being "locked" or "wait" while my BulkUpdate method is in progress. Please, I do not want to add `SET ISOLATION LEVEL READ_UNCOMMITTED` to the beginning of every read, nor add `NO LOCK` hint...are there any other solutions?

Comment: What isolation level are you setting in your transaction scope?

Comment: inserting 10,000 rows should take very little time.....

Comment: @NathanSkerl I am using READ_UNCOMMITTED, also tried SNAPSHOT

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes I agree, there are tons of logic within the code that were handed over to me that adds up to the processing time. I know I still have to optimize and fix all of them...but bottom line, let's say I reduce it to a few seconds, is there a way to prevent blocking from other users?

Comment: Please do not use READ_UNCOMMITTED; instead put your database into RCSI / Snapshot Isolation and use the default isolation level (READ_COMMITTED) in your insert. Concurrent  Readers of the data involved (row ranges) will not be blocked ; writers might be.

Comment: `also tried SNAPSHOT` Snapshot seems the obvious solution here. What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Please use TASK concept in front end side C#, split 100 or 1000 rows to each task and run simultaneously. It may be use full for you. already i will improved my application performance using like this.

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1226752/Csharp-how-to-run-tasks-in-parallel

Comment: 3 hours running process. we are reduced 10 min below... please try and let you know Okay...